# Images doesn't save in the correct location in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an image upload form in my Laravel project.

I want to save the upload image into `public/images/` location.

But image upload into `public/app/images` location.

From where this `app` coming !!

**config/filesystem.php**

```php
    'disks' => [

         'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(''),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(''),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => 'your-key',
            'secret' => 'your-secret',
            'region' => 'your-region',
            'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
        ],

    ],
```

**controller**

```php
     if($this->request->hasFile('photo')) 
     {
            $image_url = $this->request->photo->store('/images/campaign/large');

            $image = substr($image_url, strrpos($image_url, '/') + 1);
     }
```

Where is the mistake ? Anybody help please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain the line first line in controller inside if statement

Comment: `photo` is the name of the image file that comes from the `form`

Comment: Some time it may be due to cache. please clear the cache and try again

Comment: @Sagar Gautam....I have clear cash...but same problem...no change

Comment: All seems okay, it's a strange issue

Comment: yess...I have done this locally also...there is all ok...but this problem creates in my cpanel

Comment: Did you try `store(public_path('images/campaign/large'))` ?

Comment: @Harun...I tried now....but no change...it then create another horrible url.....