# Images doesn't upload in the correct location in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cpanel

I have an image upload form in my Laravel project.

I want to save the uploaded image into `public/images/` location.

But image upload into `public/app/images` location.

From where this `app` is coming!!

**config/filesystem.php**

```
'disks' => [

 'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path(''),
],

'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path(''),
    'visibility' => 'public',
],

's3' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key' => 'your-key',
    'secret' => 'your-secret',
    'region' => 'your-region',
    'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
  ],
],
```

**controller**

```
if($this->request->hasFile('photo')) 
{
    $image_url = $this->request->photo->store('/images/campaign/large');

    $image = substr($image_url, strrpos($image_url, '/') + 1);
}
```

I have applied the same code in my local project. Image uploaded there in the correct location.

But this problem happens in my cPanel server project. I have already clear cash in live server.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Hmm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56003331/images-doesnt-save-in-the-correct-location-in-laravel

Comment: @Tarasovych...no solution there

Comment: No need to duplicate questions

Answer (score 0):

I think this Controller code help you.

```
if($this->request->hasFile('photo')) 
{
    $image_url = $this->request->photo->store(public_path('images'));

    $image = substr($image_url, strrpos($image_url, '/') + 1);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? What does that code do? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can chmod -R 777 your directory file, if you using linux or mac os, or you cant clear the cache, because yesterday in my office .

This of full :
https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed to create a symbolic link for the storage path.
Please follow this link: [Larvel Public Disk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk)

In short you need to run this
`php artisan storage:link`